# gridview row indicator

Tags: asp.net

Im using Gridview in my application ...when record(s) bind in the gridview i wnt to use indicator that is if i click first record of gridview then record indicator should be shown and every key down the record indicator should be down in every record ...
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use UpdateProgress from Asp.net Ajax Library

Comment: any javascript available for this?